# ASP.NET EntityFramework CodeFirst migration doesn't create a column in the table

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a book model class with a bunch of properties. They are different types and among them is

```
[Required, StringLength(13)]
public char ISBN { get; set; }
```

but for some reason, once I added the initial migration it created all the columns correctly except for the one above. When I checked the database .sdf file, column ISBN is missing in the table. It was required for different fields (like name, author etc.) to be varchar, so I used "string" as their type, meanwhile for ISBN I need to use "char" with the length of 13. I've also try to use char[] as a type for ISBN, but the column is still missing.

Why exactly it doesn't create a column when the type of ISBN is char and which type to use instead for ISBN?

Answer (score 2):

You are saying that the field `ISBN` is required and has a length of 13, but you are declaring the property of type `char` and that means a single character.You need to change the property to this one.

```
public string ISBN { get; set; }
```

Comment: I said I tried using 'char[]' as well, but it didn't work. Thing that confuses me is the requirement. It says that Name property has to be varchar with length of 128 which I solved with using 'string' as a type in model class, but for ISBN it says that it needs to be char with the length of 13. So I should use 'string' as a type for that as well?

Comment: Well the data types in c# and sql server are a bit different and you need to learn them. And for the ISBN it is not possible to be char with the length of 13 because if it is a char that means it is just a single character. It is possible to be said that the ISBN is array of chars of length 13 and that also will be done with the type string. I've never made an array of chars using 'char[]' for creating database with entity framework so i'm not sure if that is possible, but with type string it will work for sure.